# Java heap space error is throwing " while transforming 550 mb document" eventhough heap space is higher than document size

Tags: xslt, heap-memory, transformation, saxon

A Java heap space error is thrown " while transforming 550 MB document" even though heap space is higher than a document size.

My code uses

```
1.xsl:stylesheet of xslt transformation
2.net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
3.trans.transform(new StreamSource(file), result);
```

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: Just cos the doc is 550Mb, it may take more than that to transform/parse it...

Comment: how can i find out how much time it takes to transform

Answer (score 0):

Typically with Saxon the space occupied by the source document as a tree is around 5 times the size of the lexical XML. The ratio can vary, of course, depending on the complexity of the document. So for 550Mb, allocating 3Gb should be enough. Use the -Xmx option when starting up Java to allocate enough heap space.

You're close to the limits of what can be done using a conventional in-memory transformation, so you might like to look at the options for doing a streamed transformation. For information on this, see http://saxonica.com/documentation/#!sourcedocs/streaming

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your reply..I have heap space -Xms3072m -Xmx10240m.but still the error persists.

Comment: Then I think you need to look for a different approach, e.g. streaming. (Though it might be useful to first see where the memory is going by looking at a heap analysis.)

Comment: Thank You Michael!..I will try to fix this error using streaming.